# URL replacing regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make an url that adds a `/` to all `hrefs` and `srcs` in a string.
It should only add a `/` to urls that don't have a `http://` at their beginning and that don't have `/` yet also.

If we have this:

```
<a href="ABC">...
<img src="DEFG">...
<a href="/HIJ">...
<a href="http://KLMN">...
```

The results should be something like this:

```
<a href="/ABC">...
<img src="/DEFG">...
<a href="/HIJ">...
<a href="http://KLMN">...
```

This is what i've come up till now:

```
&(href|src)="?!(\/|http::\/\/)(.+)"
```

And the replace would be

```
$1="/$2"
```

It isn't working, though.

- What am I doing wrong?
- How would the working regex have to look like

Comment: What about a URL like `foo/bar`? It does not start with `/` but contains a `/`.

Comment: I ment at the beginning of the URL

Comment: So `foo/bar` should be replaced with `/foo/bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it suffices to change just the base URI with the [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE):

```
<base href="/">
```

Now the base URI path is `/` instead of the path of the current document’s URI. But note that this affects *all* relative URIs and not just those with a relative URI path.

Comment: Sometimes when people have a problem they think; I know, I'll use Regex! Now they've got two problems.

Comment: @Aistina: You should post that as an answer so I can downvote it.

Comment: @Aistina: Let's just say it's been done before:  http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+regex+"now+you+have+two+problems"

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(href|src)="([^\/][^:]*)"/', '\1="/\2"', $str)
```

This will do what you ask, but has a little exception that any string containing a colon (:) will not get a "/" added.  That allows it to easily handle http://, ftp://, etc, but also won't work for something like "abcd:efgh".

Answer (score 0):

This will match tags with `href` or `src` in it, and the first group contains the adress.

```
(<[^<]*?(?:href|src)=")(?!http|/)(.+?)("[^<]*?>)
```

And replace with:

```
$1/$2$3
```